# script works, but the clicked radio isn't checked=checked jquery ajax POST

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, radio-button, checked

to see the error:
http://jsfiddle.net/sEdGz/2/

//the script works, but the clicked radio isn't checked=checked
    //mysql and php works good

```
$('#form1').live("click change", function() { ....
 <div class='divtoclick'>neu berechnen</div>
<form id="form1"  method="post"  name="bestellformular">

<input value="101" name="flyer_anzahl" type="radio"  /> 1.000
<input name="flyer_anzahl" type="radio" value="102" checked="checked"/>
...
```

I want to get this:

```
$('#form1').find('.divtoclick').live("click", .....
$('input#form1').live("change", .....
```

Can anybody help me? thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is your `return false`.

This will work:

```
$('#form1').live("click change", function() {
        $.ajax({
        type    : "POST",
        cache    : false,
        url        : "berechnung_ajax.php",
        data    : $(this).serializeArray(),
        success : function(data) {
                        $('#berechnung').html(data);
        }});

    return true; // return true in order not to prevent the event
    });    
});
```